# PyMongo Collection Object Not Callable

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I'm trying to create a Reddit scraper that takes the first 100 pages from the Reddit home page and stores them into MongoDB. I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'insert_one' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

Here is my code

```
import pymongo
import praw
import time


def main():
    fpid = os.fork()
    if fpid!=0:
        # Running as daemon now. PID is fpid
        sys.exit(0)

    user_agent = ("Python Scraper by djames v0.1")
    r = praw.Reddit(user_agent = user_agent)    #Reddit API requires user agent

    conn=pymongo.MongoClient()
    db = conn.reddit
    threads = db.threads


    while 1==1:    #Runs in an infinite loop, loop repeats every 30 seconds
        frontpage_pull = r.get_front_page(limit=100)    #get first 100 posts from reddit.com

        for posts in frontpage_pull:    #repeats for each of the 100 posts pulled
            data = {}
            data['title'] = posts.title
            data['text'] = posts.selftext
            threads.insert_one(data)
        time.sleep(30)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: By the way, you can say `while 1:` instead of `while 1==1:`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`insert_one()` was not added to pymongo until version 3.0. If you try calling it on a version before that, you will get the error you are seeing.

To check you version of pymongo, open up a python interpreter and enter:

```
import pymongo
pymongo.version
```

The legacy way of inserting documents with pymongo is just with `Collection.insert()`. So in your case you can change your insert line to:

```
threads.insert(data)
```

For more info, see [pymongo 2.8 documentation](https://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=insert#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert)

Comment: That was it. Thanks!